# Can I use SwiftNIO client websocket with different server websocket?

Tags: ios, websocket, network-programming, starscream, swift-nio

I am new to WebSocket, choosing between https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream and SwiftNIO,

With SwiftNIO couldn't find clear guidelines, can I Use just SwiftNIO client WebSocket in iOS. and the WebSocket server will be implemented using different web technology(Java or Spring websocket)? or if I develop client using SwiftNIO does server also has to be build using SwiftNIO?

My App is iOS 10 onwards, so I can't use apple WebSocket API(>ios13)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This package is built on SwiftNIO's WebSocket module, but gives a higher level API similar to Starscream: https://github.com/vapor/websocket-kit/

You can see example usage here: https://github.com/vapor/websocket-kit/blob/master/Tests/WebSocketKitTests/WebSocketKitTests.swift#L8-L17

Comment: Having confusion about choosing a framework, should I go with Starscream or SwiftNIO(since it is from Apple). My requirement is only for the iOS side (Server-side will be implemented in JAVA)